# ld: library not found for -lADEUMReactNative

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, appdynamics

I just create React Native project (0.64.1)

and I install appDynamic (21.4)

This is the version I found in my package.json

```
    "@appdynamics/react-native-agent": "^21.4.0",
    "appdynamics": "20.7.0",
```

How, about when I try to run the application on iOS device,

here is the error message I got:

```
ld: library not found for -lADEUMReactNative
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried the following method:

- remove the Library Search Path
- change the path of libADEUMReactNative.a under "Link Binary With Libraries" of "Build Phases"

which method I can tried? thank you

Comment: Have you followed all the instructions at https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.8/en/end-user-monitoring/mobile-real-user-monitoring/instrument-react-native-applications ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the pod version and the IOS deployment target is >= 11.
Then do pod install and build your project.